# Doubt in Definition of Inverse of $y=x^n$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, definition, inverse-function

**Attaching Snapshot**

> [image]
>
>  
>  
>   [From Calculus: [Concepts and Methods By Ken Binmore and Joan Davies](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/9wMgAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ_8estJn4AhXyFLcAHfR2Ch8Q7_IDegQIERAC), suggested by myi University]

I can't figure out whether it is a typo or I don't understand something. The very last sentence, why it says "inverse function at any $x > 0$", shouldn't it be "at any $x \ge 0$", because the domain includes $0$?

Comment: I think it is a typo. Also it is somewhat redundant to add "for every $x\geq0$".

Comment: I think this is right, since for $n=0$ you will get $0^0$ if $x=0$ is included.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think possibility $n=0$ is not included here. In that case there would be no inverse at all.

Comment: This depends on the definition of the natural numbers.

Comment: Texts are produced by us humans, not by gods. You’ll find even more evidence of carelessness and sloppiness in the answers to the problems.

Comment: See here for the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, but it is stated there "For each $y\geq0$ the equation $y=x^n$ has a unique solution". That indicates that they work with $\mathbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarification

Comment: @Lubin I don't doubt that there are typos, but it is a bit worrisome when it is a textbook. It is hard enough to understand even without typos sometimes, and it seems to be a bit unorthodox due to using a lot of Linear Algebra, sometimes fuelling doubts further because it is harder to compare with other textbooks. Anyway thanks for the answers.

Comment: Isn't that Ken Binmore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Although what they say is not wrong, they could say more than what they do.

Comment: If $n\geq 0$ then you will get $0^0$ if $x=0$ is included.

Comment: But the function isn’t invertible away from $0$ if $n=0$, so this is implicitly excluded—the statement about unique solutions doesn’t hold, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner